# How do i extend a model to fill in a grid without having the foreign keys validated upon saving?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, telerik

We have a design paradigm we are considering standardizing to but it has some problems and none of us have a good solution for it.

1) We create a core model that contains all the general fields and index values of any foreign keys.  This is tied to a table and in our design will be edited in a popup from our grids.

2) a second class inherits the first one and has all foreign key references.  This class would populate grids.  This would allow us to show specific info from foreign tables.

**Now for the Problem**:  The popup model must match the model for the grid (we are using telerik grids) and when we save, EF tries to validate anything even remotely connected to the table through the foreign keys and anything they reference through foreign keys etc.  We once had a record throw an error because we tried to edit an order and the truck assigned to the order's driver was missing mileage info.

I tried (successfully) to replace foreign key references with notmapped fields and load them in the index file but it was slow compared to EF.  I looped through each record in the grid (for each) and looked up each matching model and added it.

Another programmer got around the problem by creating two completely different models and having the 2nd model with the foreign keys point to an alias of the table.  Personally this feels illegal to me.

Our third developer did something similar but pulled data from a view.  He actually had a good reason though as the view had a calculated "locked" column based on financial settlement.

So there you have it.  Three different methods to solve the same issue.  I've also tried "exclude" from the post but i was evidently doing it wrong.

We considered shutting off the validation in EF but nobody is familiar enough with it to know if it kills the validation on that page as well.   MVC is a recent step for us.  Our site was originally in asp.  The driving force in fact was our orders grid which could take a minute to load.

**So after i gave you all that info, here's the question: ** What is the best way to set our models up?  I am the junior programmer and feel like we are doing it wrong in all three scenarios.   More importantly i feel like it's completely unnecessary.  I would like to bind a model to a grid with full data that inherits a core model but that's all we validate.  How is that done?

Example controller:

```
namespace DispatchCrude.Controllers
{
[Authorize(Roles = "viewShipperTimeCardWorkTypeRates")]
public class ShipperTimeCardWorkTypeRatesController : _DBController
{                      
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(int? orderid, int? typeid)
    {
        // Send through any filters
        if (orderid != null)
            ViewBag.OrderID = orderid;

        if (typeid != null)
            ViewBag.TypeID = typeid;

        return View();
    }

    // Read
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    virtual public ContentResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request = null, int id = 0, int? orderid = null)
    {
        return Read(request, null, id, orderid);
    }

    protected ContentResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ModelStateDictionary modelState, int id = 0, int? orderid = null)
    {
        var data = db.ShipperTimeCardWorkTypeRates
                    .Where(m => m.ID == id || id == 0).ToList();
        if (orderid != null)
        {
            var validRates = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(@"SELECT R.ID
                    FROM dbo.viewOrder O
                    CROSS APPLY dbo.fnShipperTimeCardRates(isnull(O.OrderDate, O.DueDate), null, null,
                        O.TicketTypeID, O.DestTicketTypeID, O.CustomerID, CarrierTypeID, O.CarrierID, DriverGroupID, O.DriverID, O.TruckTypeID, O.ProductGroupID,
                        O.DestinationID, O.OriginID, O.DestStateID, O.OriginStateID, O.DestRegionID, O.OriginRegionID, O.ProducerID, 0) R
                    WHERE O.ID = " + orderid);
            data = data.Where(m => validRates.Contains(m.ID)).ToList();

        }
        return ToJsonResult(data, request, modelState);
    }

    // Create
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "createShipperTimeCardWorkTypeRates")]
    public ActionResult Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ShipperTimeCardWorkTypeRateBase timeCardWorkTypeRates)
    {

        // Create functionality is now taken care of in the update function as of Kevin's 2017 update to how MVC controllers are written
        return Update(request, timeCardWorkTypeRates);  
    }

    // Update
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "editShipperTimeCardWorkTypeRates")]
    public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ShipperTimeCardWorkTypeRateBase timeCardWorkTypeRates)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime checkDate1;
            DateTime checkDate2;
            bool success1 = DateTime.TryParse(timeCardWorkTypeRates.EffectiveDate.ToString(), out checkDate1);
            bool success2 = DateTime.TryParse(timeCardWorkTypeRates.EndDate.ToString(), out checkDate2);
            if (success1 && success2 && checkDate2.Subtract(checkDate1).TotalHours < 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Update", "End Date must be equal to or later than Start Date.");    
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Create new record or update existing record
                db.AddOrUpdateSave(User.Identity.Name, timeCardWorkTypeRates);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Update", ex.Message); // TODO: use a common routine to "cleanup" db generated errors
            return App_Code.JsonStringResult.Create(new[] { timeCardWorkTypeRates }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
        return Read(request, ModelState, timeCardWorkTypeRates.ID);
    }

    // Delete (Deactivate)
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "deleteShipperTimeCardWorkTypeRates")]
    public ActionResult Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ShipperTimeCardWorkTypeRateBase shipperTimeCardWorkTypeRate)
    {
        // Delete the record
        db.ShipperTimeCardWorkTypeBases.Attach(shipperTimeCardWorkTypeRate);
        db.ShipperTimeCardWorkTypeBases.Remove(shipperTimeCardWorkTypeRate);
        db.SaveChanges(User.Identity.Name);

        return null;
    }

    public ContentResult getBestMatch(int orderid, int? typeid = null)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM fnOrderShipperTimeCardRates(" + orderid + ")";
        if (typeid != null)
            sql += " WHERE WorkTypeID = " + typeid;

        var bestmatchids = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql);
        return ToJsonResult(bestmatchids.ToList());
    }
}
```

}
`

the popup editor uses @model DispatchCrude.Models.ShipperTimeCardWorkTypeRate
the grid uses the same.  This split works but EF won't allow us to set two models to the same table, and the inheriting didn't work either.

What do we do?

Comment: What does your DbContext look like?  Have you done migrations?  What are the constraints on the table in your database?  Are you sure it's EF causing the pain and not the database constraints? Can we see an actual error message?

Comment: final question first:  Yes.  Some of our models (due to requirement changes by our clients) are more restrictive than the database is so some old records would no longer pass if edited.  Constraints are usually set up as:  foreign key references must be larger than 0.  Other random fields may have a "required" tag on them as needed.  I don't know what migrations are actually.  

An example error i just had was (possibly not worded exactly) 'field BOLHeaderTemplate is required" which was on the origin table when i was editing a route.  It's a field we've made required in the origin model.